# Data binding json model in a boostrap-table

Tags: c#, json, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a bootstrap table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and would like to data bind my viewModel by encoding it in JSON.

My viewModel contains an simple collection "IEnumerable Entries".

In my view I encode my model to JSON format :

```
 $(function () {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.Entries))',
            columns: [...all the columns descriptions...
```

The issue is when I debug my website I see in each cell of the table a single minus " - " char. I don't have any error when I inspect the page and the json string is correctly formatted when I log it in the console.

What could be wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

okey ... found :

```
<script> to <script type="text/jscript">
```

and quotes should be removed from data

```
data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.Entries))
```